# SQL/Postgres: comparing timestamps across rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, timespan

I have a table called `trips` that looks like this:

```
 id | vehicle_id | start_time          | end_time            |
----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
  1 |          1 | 2014-06-16 22:00:00 | 2014-06-24 03:30:00 |
  2 |          1 | 2014-06-24 05:00:00 | 2014-06-28 05:00:00 |
  3 |          2 | 2014-06-23 02:00:00 | 2014-06-30 04:00:00 |
 ...
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7c92e/1 (PG 9.2 only because 9.3 was overloaded on SQL Fiddle the time.)

`start_time` and `end_time` are both timestamps.

What I'd like to do find trips involving the same `vehicle_id` where the `start_time` of a subsequent trip takes place on the same calendar day or the next calendar day of the `end_time` of a prior trip.

As an example, rows with ID `1` and `2` above would be returned, because:

- `2`'s `start_time` takes place on the same calendar day (`2014-06-24`) as `1`; and
- both rows have the same `vehicle_id`

It's quite possible this isn't sensible to do in SQL. Any advice, tips or pointers to relevant Postgres functions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to values from the "previous" row can be done using [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). In this case the `lag()` function.

```
select id, vehicle_id, start_time, end_time
from (
  select id, vehicle_id, start_time, end_time,
         start_time::date - lag(end_time::date) over (partition by vehicle_id order by start_time) as diff_to_prev,
         end_time::date - lead(start_time::date) over (partition by vehicle_id order by start_time) as diff_to_next
  from trips
) t
where diff_to_prev = 0
   or diff_to_next = 0;
```

"previous" only make sense if you also supply a sort order. From your description it sounds as if you want to use the `id` column to determine the order of the rows. But if you can easily change that to use `start_date`.

The statement calculates the difference in days to the next row and the previous row. If only the difference to the previous was taken, the row with `id=1` would not be returned.

The expression `start_time::date` simply converts the timestamp to a date to remove the time part. This also has the effect that the difference is an integer value (in days) rather than an `interval`.

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7c92e/5

Comment: Thanks very much! This looks the right approach to me. I'm not getting any results though: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7c92e/3

Comment: @Aupajo: my assumption that you want it sorted by `id` apparently was wrong. Just change the `order by id` to `order by start_time` and you'll get the ids: 20,22,4692,5344 Not sure why you expect 5297,5355 because 5297 ends on 2014-10-27 and 5355 starts on 2014-10-28 which is clearly not the same day.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The goal is to find trips that “[take] place on the same calendar day or the next calendar day” – but you've shown me enough that I can take it from here :) Thanks.

Comment: If you want to include the next day, you can change the condition to `diff_to_next <= 1`